# How do I make masks to set all of image background, except the text, to white?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to extract the text in this region to run OCR, but the stray black edges are interfering with some results. Is there a way to isolate this text?

[image]

After finding this contour, I've cropped it out of the original image with a black background mask. I'm not too sure how to change the background to white, nor can I figure out a way to get rid of the black edges around the contour. Thresholding the image seems to get rid of some of the black pixels in the text, which I don't want.

Ideally the output should be simply the black text, and a white background.

This is a section in the code of the original masking that I've attempted-

```py
mask = np.ones(orig_img.shape).astype(orig_img.dtype)
cv2.fillPoly(mask, [cnt], (255,255,255))
cropped_contour = cv2.bitwise_and(orig_img, mask)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To isolate the text, one approach is to obtain the bounding box coordinates of the desired ROI and then mask that ROI onto a blank white image. The main idea is:

- Convert image to grayscale
- Threshold image
- Dilate image to connect text as a single bounding box
- Find contours and filter used contour area to find ROI
- Place ROI onto mask

Threshold image (left) then dilate to connect text (right)

[image]
[image]

You can find contours using `cv2.boundingRect()` then once you have the ROI, you can place this ROI onto the mask with

```
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype='uint8')
mask.fill(255)
mask[y:y+h, x:x+w] = original_image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
```

Find contours then filter for ROI (left), final result (right)

[image]
[image]

Depending on your image size, you may need to adjust the filter for the contour area.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

original_image = cv2.imread('1.png')
image = original_image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=5)

# Find contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

# Create a blank white mask
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype='uint8')
mask.fill(255)

# Iterate thorugh contours and filter for ROI
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 15000:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)
        mask[y:y+h, x:x+w] = original_image[y:y+h, x:x+w]

cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.imshow("image", image)
cv2.imshow("dilate", dilate)
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("result", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Thanks! Dilating and then finding a bounding box for the text itself is pretty intuitive. I'm wondering if it would be an issue if the text was somehow touching the edge of the polygon (or barely not touching it). Dilating the text then, might have no contour, since the text will be connected to the white background.

Comment: You may run into problems if the text is close to the edge since it merges with the exterior. It would be difficult to find the ROI if the text was connected to the background